# I am going to run a C# mono program when PI4 start

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, mono, autostart

I am going to run a C# program with Mono when the PI4 start.
It is better to run with CMD (show in the monitor)
Does anyone know how can i do this?

I have tried this but dont work:
sudo nano ~/.config/autostart/lxterm-autostart.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Terminal autostart
Comment=Start a terminal and list directory
Exec=/usr/bin/lxterm 'mono /home/pi/Desktop/run/main/ABC.exe'
```

Comment: Next time please make sure you use the right tag.

Comment: thanks 
any solution?